# No members available of 'array' class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm probably facing the stupidest error so far.
I was studying for my programming final exam in Visual Studio 2022 and my arrays suddenly stopped working. I define the array like this,

```
int arr[10] = {};
```

But when I try to use array functions for my array,

```
arr.
```

After putting '.', IntelliSense says "No members available" and no array functions listed.

Is this a bug or am I just missing something here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? C-style arrays do not have member functions

Comment: well in c++ there are no methods for a simple array. look into the vector class

Comment: @UnholySheep I want to use size() function. I also can't define the array using array<type,size> approach. It throws this error,

array counts<int, 5> = {};
->counts is not a template
->argument list for class template "std::array" is missing

Comment: the template parameters go on the type, not the variable name: `std::array<int, 5> counts = {}`

Comment: c-arrays have no members. For once Intellisense is right to the point. Use `std::array` or the non-member `std::size`

Comment: don't guess how it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have initialised is C-style array (as @UnholySheep has already pointed out).

```cpp
// C-style arrays

// This allocates a C-style array of 10 elements of type int
int myArray[10];

// C++ style arrays

// Include the array implementation provided by libc++
#include <array>

// This allocates C++ style array
std::array<int, 10> myArray;
```

With C++ style arrays you'll get member functions like `end()`, `begin()`, etc, but not with C-style arrays.

Also if you are new to the language, I would suggest you to look at cppreference for the documentation for the language features, it's quite accurate. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array is the link for documentation for std::array